# When i run the android tab swipe getting error

Tags: android

```
package actions.com.mytabswipe;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabAdapter tabAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPAger);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < tabAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab " + i).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

> when i run this am getting error 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378): Process: actions.com.mytabswipe, PID: 2378
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{actions.com.mytabswipe/actions.com.mytabswipe.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-03 04:40:10.277:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   actions.com.mytabswipe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 02-03
>   04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   02-03 04:40:10.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):   ... 11 more
>
> My Custom Adapter package actions.com.mytabswipe;
>
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
>
> /**  * Created by Murali on 03-Feb-15.  */ public class TabAdapter
>   extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>
> ```
> public TabAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
>     super(manager);
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>
>
>     switch (position) {
>         case 0:
>             new Fragment1();
>         case 1:
>           new Fragment2();
>     }
>     return new Fragment1();
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return 2;
> } } My fragment, package actions.com.mytabswipe;
> ```
>
> import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
>   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import
>   android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import
>   android.view.ViewGroup;
>
> /**  * Created by Murali on 03-Feb-15.  */ public class Fragment2
>   extends Fragment {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
> } }
> ```

Comment: use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` to get ActionBar

Comment: Your actionBar variable is null because you used getActionBar().

Comment: vipluv, what will do for that

Comment: Hi  ρяσѕρєя K, getSupportActionBar() showing error

Answer (score 0):

for 'fragment' use below code to access action bar

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: where are the fragments which you are calling to swipe ?

Comment: Using viewpager pagechangelistener am using

Comment: @ Sukhwant Singh Grewal, i added ,check  above

Comment: hi, now the error was cleared but page change same fragment showing

Comment: finally i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

This error will get by the theme. so Change the theme in manifest xml file to action

Comment: Thanks i really got the answer after change the manifest theme